# Which of the following subsets of the real line is compact?

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> Put $\theta:= \frac{\pi}{2019}$ and let $\mathbb{N}$ denote the set of positive integers. Which of the following subsets of the real line is compact?
>
> (a) $\{\frac{sin(n\theta)}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
>
> (b) $\{\frac{cos(n\theta)}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
>
> (c) $\{\frac{tan(n\theta)}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$
>
> (d) None of the above.

Definition of compact set: A set K ⊆ R is compact if every sequence
in K has a sub-sequence that converges to a limit that is also in K.

Characterization of Compactness in R Theorem: A set K ⊆ R
is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded.

Here I am unable to find the closed and boundedness property. For e.g.: $\{\frac{sin(n\theta)}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ and $\{\frac{cos(n\theta)}{n}| n \in \mathbb{N}\}$ are bounded, but I am unable to determine whether closed or not.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How many distinct values does $\sin(n\theta)$ take as $n$ runs over all positive integers? Is $0$ one of them? Do those two facts alone allow you to determine whether the set in (a) is closed?

Comment: $sin(n\theta)$ can take infinitely many values and yes 0 is one of them. So you are saying 0 acts as the limit point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: The sequences in a), b) and c) all have $0$ as the only limit point. So they are closed iff $0$ is  a member of the sequence.

Comment: Can you please explain why does c) has 0 as the limit point? In a) , b) its clear as $n \rightarrow \infty$, both tend to zero.

Comment: @HeavyMetaL It is impossible for $n \theta$ to get close to $\pm \frac {\pi} 2 mod (2\pi)$  and this makes $\tan (n\theta)$ bounded.

Comment: Can you please explain why does c) has 0 as the limit point? Thankyou for the boundedness part: +1

Comment: @HeavyMetaL If $a_n$ is bounded then $\frac {a_n} n \to 0$.

Comment: So, in (b), $cos{(n\theta)}$ cannot reach 0 from the above reasoning. But $\frac{cos{(n\theta)} }{n} \rightarrow 0$, but 0 is not a member of the sequence, hence b) is not compact. Is this correct?

Comment: @HeavyMetaL Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105932/discussion-between-heavymetal-and-kavi-rama-murthy).